# Opening Packages on shabbat that arrived Friday

Tags: shabbat

If a package is to arrive at my door before shabbat can I then take it in/open it on Shabbat (if the contents are not *muktza*) or are there further issues besides techum, e.g., Kinyanim or others.

SUB-QUESTION 1:

"My door" is in a *carmelis*.

SUB-QUESTION 2:

"My door" is in my *reshus hayochid*.

TO MAKE THE QUESTION EASIER TO ANSWER:

It is possible to open the package in a permitted way on Shabbos; the contents are needed for Shabbos.

Comment: I'm confused. What issues do you think exist already and how are they dealt with?

Comment: Carefully considering @DoubleAA’s enquiry, including an examination of the *techum* issue, you may discover that the “issues” are circumvented even when a package arrives *on* Shabbat.

Comment: @user15464 Not quite; that asks about packages which arrived *on* Shabbos. Here they arrived *before* Shabbos, which perhaps lends itself to being more lenient.

Comment: @DonielF Bichlal masayim Mane the questioner is asking about everything in the other question besides Techum. this is a duplicate as no new repercussions can come out of this question

Comment: Also it may be asur to rip open the package on Shabbos

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Mordechai and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @user15464 I disagree. You note there is a difference (techum) between this question and the other one (package arrives on Shabbos). Therefore technically this is not a duplicate. With respect, it is your 'answer' to this question that no new repercussions can come out.